# how to fix: sqlite3.dll not found on delphi data explorer?

Tags: delphi, sqlite

I am following the tutorial at: 
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_SQLite_%28iOS_and_Android%29

but I stuck at the 6th step (test the connection) which always give me:
failed: "sqlite3.dll not found"

In fact I have the sqlite3.dll 64 bit which I put it in c:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder and sqlite3.dll 32 bit which I put it in c:\Windows\System32

I do believe that the sqlite is run in my system because I can use it using FireDAC.

What should I do to fix this?

Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: This was asked a couple of weeks ago I think. Have a look for the dupe.

Comment: You have the DLLs the wrong way around.  Despite the folder names, system32 is for 64-bit Dlls and SysWOW64 for 32-bit ones - another stroke of genius by MS.  Make sure the one you want is findable via your system path.

Comment: @MartynA, thank you very much for the information. After put the files on its right folder (64 bit to the System32 and 32 bit to the SysWoW64) now the testing is success.
So I consider the problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: Good, I'll write that up as an answer and I'd be grateful if you could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, You have the DLLs the wrong way around. Despite the folder names, system32 is for 64-bit Dlls and SysWOW64 for 32-bit ones.  So, you should swap the DLLs' locations.

Make sure the one you want is findable via your system path.

Comment: Would be much better not to put 3rd party DLLs like this into the system folders.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  I agree.  It's a pity some installers (s/ware I mean) still do this when they've no need to.